# Newline in textarea,reperesents one character in javascript, but represents 2 character in oracle database

Tags: html, oracle11g, special-characters, oracle-sqldeveloper, enter

I have create a table in oracle database with a fields message varchar(160).

Now I am taking input from html textarea.

When I am taking 160 character within it whitespace,special character then i could insert 160 character. But If I take a newline (By pressing enter button) with another 159 character then  Warning shows:
Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-12899: value too large for column .. (actual: 161, maximum: 160)

that means each enter button takes as a 2 character for database. I have tested it for entering 5 newline and get 10 character for database.

I have reading this in detail and come to know that each newline represents as '\r\n', thus for each enter, 2 character is used.

Now if I replace '\r\n' with '\n' then database takes a string '\n' which will work fine when I will print it in a web page. But I need data from database, so I should not use '\n' in database.

Now what can I do to insert newline/break as a single character in Database?

Comment: You can't. Convert from two to one when writing to the DB, and back from one to two when reading for display? The client should do both really.

Comment: ok, then how can I do it for both ?